# android app does not scale from 7 to 10

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I wrote my app for my 7" tablet. It fit well on this screen.
App is based on nested LinearLayout.
All LinearLayout are set for with and height to match_parent or fill_parent.
I have no fixed any with or height with dpi.
So when I launched my application on a 10-inch tablet, I thought it would fit to the new screen. Instead, the application occupies the same space when running on the 7-inch tablet.
My application should run only on 7-inch tablet or 10 inches.
Why my application does not fit the new screen?

Now I read a post about folder layout -layout-large for 7" tablet - layout-xlarge for 10" tablet .
All my xml layout are in °layout° folder.
I have to create these new folders? And copy my xml layout files in these new folders?
Where can I find an explanation on how to set up an application for it to fit properly from 7 to 10 inches?
Thanks in advance!
Sergio

Also I am using:
DP units for padding/margins and SP units for fonts and weights .

Captures:
[Capture7inch1024x600.JPG](http://www.sergiobertini.it/temp/Capture7inch1024x600.JPG)
[Capture10inch1280x800.JPG](http://www.sergiobertini.it/temp/Capture10inch1280x800.JPG)

Here the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:background="@drawable/wood_floor"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ScorerActivity" >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/custom_txt_opal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblAvv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Punti Avversari" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
         >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPuntiPartita"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Punti Giocatore"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30"
         android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTotalePuntiPartita"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Punti Partita" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione7"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="7"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione1"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="1"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione8"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="8"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione2"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="2"
                android:text="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione9"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="9"
                android:text="9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione3"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="3"
                android:text="3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione10"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="10"
                android:text="10" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione4"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="4"
                android:text="4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione11"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="11"
                android:text="11" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione5"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="5"
                android:text="5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione12"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="12"
                android:text="12" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAzione6"
                style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goStartAzione"
                android:tag="6"
                android:text="6" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_txt_lemon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblMagliaNumero"
                style="@style/BaseTextSize"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblNomeGiocatore"
                style="@style/BaseTextSize"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHalfCourt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/halfcourt4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFallo1"
                style="@style/txtStyleWhiteShadow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_opal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="setFallo"
                android:tag="1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFallo2"
                style="@style/txtStyleWhiteShadow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_opal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="setFallo"
                android:tag="2"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFallo3"
                style="@style/txtStyleWhiteShadow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_opal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="setFallo"
                android:tag="3"
                android:text="3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFallo4"
                style="@style/txtStyleWhiteShadow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_opal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="setFallo"
                android:tag="4"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFallo5"
                style="@style/txtStyleWhiteShadow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_opal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="setFallo"
                android:tag="5"
                android:text="5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnT2Ok"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="28"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_check_48"
                android:onClick="mngActionsT2"
                android:tag="T2r"
                android:text="T2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnT2Ko"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="28"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_delete_48"
                android:onClick="mngActionsT2"
                android:tag="T2e"
                android:text="T2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtT2rrtt"
                style="@style/BaseTextSize"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="00/00" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtT2rrttperc"
                style="@style/BaseTextSize"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="19"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0%" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnT3Ok"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="28"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_check_48"
                android:onClick="mngActionsT3"
                android:tag="T3r"
                android:text="T3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnT3Ko"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="28"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_delete_48"
                android:onClick="mngActionsT3"
                android:tag="T3e"
                android:text="T3" />
                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtT3rrtt"
                style="@style/BaseTextSize"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="00/00" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtT3rrttperc"
                style="@style/BaseTextSize"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="19"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0%" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTLOk"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="28"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_check_48"
                android:onClick="mngActionsTL"
                android:tag="TLr"
                android:text="TL" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTLKo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="28"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_delete_48"
                android:onClick="mngActionsTL"
                android:tag="TLe"
                android:text="TL" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTLrrtt"
                style="@style/BaseTextSize"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="00/00" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTLrrttperc"
                style="@style/BaseTextSize"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="19"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="%" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/txtrimbAttOk"
                style="@style/btnStyleSandrift"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="mngActionsRimb"
                android:tag="rimbAttAdd"
                android:text="+ R. Att." />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/txtrimbDifOk"
                style="@style/btnStyleSandrift"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="mngActionsRimbDif"
                android:tag="rimbDifAdd"
                android:text="+ R. Dif." />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/txtPerseOk"
                style="@style/btnStyleSandrift"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="mngActionsPallep"
                android:tag="pallepAdd"
                android:text="+ P. Perse" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/txtRecupeOk"
                style="@style/btnStyleSandrift"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="mngActionsPaller"
                android:tag="pallerAdd"
                android:text="+ P. Rec." />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnUndoLastAct"
                style="@style/btnStyleSandrift"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="goUndo"
                android:text="UNDO ultima azione" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLastAction"
        style="@style/BaseTextSize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ultima azione salvata: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLastActionDesc"
        style="@style/BaseTextSize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the layout file. Please also consider taking screenshots of the app to illustrate your problem.

Comment: I have to capture for 7" and 10". How can I add to this post?

Comment: Sorry but I have not at least 10 reputation to upload an image! :-(

Comment: You can upload the images elsewhere on the Internet and link to them from your post.

Answer (score 1):

> Why my application does not fit the new screen?

Because your content does not fill the screen. A button with width and height of `wrap_content`, for example, will become bigger if the *content* is bigger, not if the *screen* is bigger.

You declined to post your layout file, as I suggested. As such, nobody is going to be able to give you much in the way of concrete advice. You can use Hierarchy View to get a better sense for how your layout rules are being applied, and from there you need to decide how to adjust those rules and/or provide larger content to more effectively use the space.

> Now I read a post about folder layout -layout-large for 7" tablet - layout-xlarge for 10" tablet . All my xml layout are in °layout° folder.

That means that you will use the same layout XML resources for all screen sizes. That's not necessarily a problem.

> have to create these new folders?

You could, if you wanted to use them. For a tablet-centric app, as yours appears to be, your `android:minSdkVersion` should be at least 11, in which case you could use `-wNNNdp` resource sets, to set the dividing line where you want it to be, based off of the screen width in the current orientation.

You use multiple resource sets this way when you have *different* resources to be applied at *different* times for the *same* role: different layouts for different screen sizes, different string translations for different languages, etc.

> And copy my xml layout files in these new folders?

Only as a starting point. If you are bothering with a different layout resource set, the point is that the XML layout files differ. If you want to always use the same layout file, you don't need to set up different directories and don't need to copy files around.

You can think of resource sets as a bit like CSS media queries. There, you set up CSS rules to be applied under certain conditions. With resources, different resource sets use suffixes on the directory name to indicate "rules" to be applied under certain circumstances.

> Where can I find an explanation on how to set up an application for it to fit properly from 7 to 10 inches?

There's lots of coverage of this in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), and any serious Android book will cover it extensively as well.

Comment: @Sergio: It's pretty much as I expected. Your current design does a fine job of utilizing the width. And, your buttons and such should be OK in their current size. You may want to do change your rules for your half-court `ImageView` so it can grow a bit. Otherwise, either find something *new* to add for 10" tablets that can take up the space, or redesign your layout to better take advantage of the additional height.

Answer (score 0):

you must be sure that android:xlargeScreens="true" in the supports screens in the manifest file `<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />`

Comment: This is my:<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html  delete android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found why my app does not fill all space horizontally.
Under "res" there is a folder "values-sw720dp-land" with a file dimens.xml that contains:

```
<resources>

<!--
     Customize dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml (such as
     screen margins) for sw720dp devices (e.g. 10" tablets) in landscape here.
-->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">128dp</dimen>
```

I don't know why there is a horizontal margin so big!
Now I have to work to better set my layout.
Thanks to all for help.
Sergio

Comment: Since the answer to your question was simply a bad configuration on your end, I would just delete this question, since it can't help anyone else.

Comment: I agree with you.
But you really do not think this post will be useful to others?
I have found the answer to my problem by reading many other posts, many of which responded to the same questions but always something different.
In any case, thanks to Stack!